# Why kubectx failed? multiple files in KUBECONFIG are currently not supported

Tags: kubernetes

I added KUBECONFIG

```
echo $KUBECONFIG
/home/miki/.kube/config:
```

When I try

```
kubectx
```

I got

```
error: kubeconfig error: failed to load: cannot determine kubeconfig path: multiple files in KUBECONFIG are currently not supported
```

In my config file I have both k3s and aws clusters.

```
   server: https://127.0.0.1:6443
  name: default
 server: https://3ECADDEA56D1B423B5D649212BDC10A1.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:57711112222:cluster/pizd-cluster
```

How to use kubectx to avoid error?

Comment: Refer to this [Git link](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/issues/211) to resolve your issue

Comment: Is your issue resolved by referring above Git link

Comment: No,not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've configured this using a individual file for each individual cluster, so i set the KUBECONFIG var with all files separated by two points ":"

```
> echo $KUBECONFIG 
'/home/user/cluster1.config:/home/user/cluster2.config:/home/user/cluster3.config'
```

each file with your own configuration, its works finelly to me.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit late to answer this, but i was getting the same error, since I was actually using different config files for each cluster in a specific folder and setting the paths in KUBECONFIG env

[image]

I fixed it with this powershell script

```
$LIST = (Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.y*ml -Recurse -File -Name | ForEach-Object {          
        [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($_)
    })

$JOINEDLIST = ($LIST -join ";")

$DEFAULT_CONFIG = "C:\Users\michele.ietri\.kube\config"

$FULLLIST = "$DEFAULT_CONFIG;$JOINEDLIST"

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('KUBECONFIG', "$FULLLIST", 'User')
    
kubectl config view --raw > $DEFAULT_CONFIG

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('KUBECONFIG', "$DEFAULT_CONFIG", 'User')
```

basically it updates the KUBECONFIG env var, then rewrite the default config file with the single raw value compiled by kubectl itself

Answer (score 1):

Wow `@Michele letri` that is exactly what I needed and fixed this issue for me! Thank you! What I decided to do is put the following in my .zshrc (or .bash_profile). This makes sure that any changes I made in my custom-contexts folder automatically get re-joined when I reconnect, or I could also just run `kube-reload` after making any changes to re-join them instantly without restarting my session.

```bash
kube_reload() {
    trap 'trap - ERR; return' ERR
    silent="false"
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        case "$1" in
            -s|--silent) silent="true" ;;
            -h|--help) echo "Usage: kube-reload [-s|--silent]"; return 0 ;;
            *) echo "Invalid option: $1"; echo "Usage: kube-reload [-s|--silent]"; return 1 ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
    [ "${silent}" = "false" ] && { echo "Reloading kubeconfigs . . ."; }
    if test -d ~/.kube; then
        export KUBECONFIG=""
        KUBECONFIG_REAL=~/.kube/config
        touch "${KUBECONFIG_REAL}"
        custom_contexts_dir=~/.kube/custom-contexts
        mkdir -p ~/.kube/custom-contexts
        custom_contexts_dir="$(cd "${custom_contexts_dir}" && pwd)"
        [ "${silent}" = "false" ] && { echo "Custom Contexts Directory: '${custom_contexts_dir}'"; }
        for file in $(find ~/.kube/custom-contexts/ -name '*.config' \( -type f -o -type l \)); do
            [ "${silent}" = "false" ] && { printf "\t${file}\n" | sed -E "s|${custom_contexts_dir}|\.|"; }
            file="$(echo "${file}" | sed "s/\/\//\//")" # replace double slashes to single
            export KUBECONFIG="${KUBECONFIG}:${file}"
        done
        if [ "${KUBECONFIG}" = "" ]; then
            [ "${silent}" = "false" ] && { echo "No custom kubeconfigs found"; }
        else
            kubectl config view --raw >"${KUBECONFIG_REAL}"
            [ "${silent}" = "false" ] && { echo "All contexts successfully joined into '${KUBECONFIG_REAL}'"; }
        fi
        export KUBECONFIG="${KUBECONFIG_REAL}"
    fi
    return 0
}
alias kube-reload="kube_reload"
kube-reload -s
```